# store given answers of a Quiz App into array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, firebase, react-state

I'm building a quiz app in React, I have created a quiz card with 4 answers for each question, the question and the answers in the card change every time you click on "Submit".

Here is my code:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      setValue(true);
      let updatedAnswers = [...givenAnswer, event.target.value];
      setGivenAnswer(updatedAnswers);
    };
  
    console.log(givenAnswer)
  
    const handleSelectedItem = (index) => {
      setClickedIndex(index);
      
    };
  
    
    const goToNext = () => {
      setCurrentQuestionIndex((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      setValue(false);
      setClickedIndex(null);
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const transformQuestions = (questionObj) => {
        const loadedQuestions = [];
  
        for (const questionKey in questionObj) {
          loadedQuestions.push({
            id: questionKey,
            id_test: questionObj[questionKey].id_test,
            tipologia_domanda: questionObj[questionKey].tipologia_domanda,
            testo: questionObj[questionKey].testo,
            immagine: questionObj[questionKey].immagine,
            eliminata: questionObj[questionKey].eliminata,
          });
        }
        setQuestions(loadedQuestions);
      };
      getQuestions(
        {
          method: 'GET',
          url: baseURL_Q,
        },
        transformQuestions
      );
    }, [getQuestions]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const transformAnswers = (answerObj) => {
        const loadedAnswers = [];
  
        for (const answerKey in answerObj) {
          loadedAnswers.push({
            id: answerKey,
            domanda_id: answerObj[answerKey].domanda_id,
            corretta: answerObj[answerKey].corretta,
            testo: answerObj[answerKey].testo,
            immagine: answerObj[answerKey].immagine,
          });
        }
        setAnswers(loadedAnswers);
      };
      getAnswers(
        {
          method: 'GET',
          url: baseURL_A,
        },
        transformAnswers
      );
    }, [getAnswers]);
  
    let questionsTitle = questions.map((element) => `${element.testo}`);
    let questionIndicator = (currentQuestionIndex * 100) / questionsTitle.length;
    let answerQuestionId = questions.map((q) => {
      let temp = answers.filter(
        (element) => `${element.domanda_id}` === `${q.id}`
      );
      return temp;
    });
    let sortedAnswers = answerQuestionId.map((item) =>
      item.map((innerItem) => `${innerItem.testo}`)
    );
  
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={4}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              minWidth: 275,
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
              paddingLeft: '100%',
              position: 'center',
            }}
          >
            <Card
              variant='outlined'
              sx={{
                minWidth: 400,
              }}
            >
              {onTime ? (
                <>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Grid container spacing={0}>
                      <Grid item xs={8}>
                        <Typography
                          variant='h5'
                          component='div'
                          fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                        >
                          Nome Test
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <CountDown setOnTime={setOnTime} seconds={1000} />
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
  
                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                      <Box sx={{ width: '100%', mr: 1 }}>
                        <LinearProgress
                          variant='determinate'
                          value={questionIndicator}
                        />
                      </Box>
                      <Box sx={{ minWidth: 35 }}>
                        <Typography variant='body2' color='text.secondary'>
                          {currentQuestionIndex + 1}/{questionsTitle.length + 1}
                        </Typography>
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
  
                    <Typography
                      sx={{ mb: 1.5, mt: 1.5, textAlign: 'center' }}
                      fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                      fontWeight={'bold'}
                    >
                      {questionsTitle[currentQuestionIndex]}
                    </Typography>
  
                    {sortedAnswers.length > 0 && (
                      <ButtonGroup
                        fullWidth
                        orientation='vertical'
                        onClick={handleSubmit}
                        
                      >
                        {sortedAnswers[currentQuestionIndex].map(
                          (answer, index) => (
                            <ListItemButton
                              selected={clickedIndex === index}
                              onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(index)}
                              key={index}
                            >
                              {answer}
                            </ListItemButton>
                          )
                        )}
                      </ButtonGroup>
                    )}
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    <Button
                      onClick={goToNext}
                      disabled={!value}
                      variant='contained'
                      size='small'
                    >
                      Avanti
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Typography
                    sx={{ mb: 1.5, mt: 1.5 }}
                    fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                    fontWeight={'bold'}
                    align={'center'}
                  >
                    TEMPO ESAURITO
                  </Typography>
                  <NavLink> Torna ai Test</NavLink>
                </>
              )}
            </Card>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
}
```

I want to store the given answers in an array so that I can check later if they are correct. I've tried to do this:

```js
    const [givenAnswer, setGivenAnswer] = useState([]);
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      setValue(true);
      let updatedAnswers = [...givenAnswer, event.target.value];
      setGivenAnswer(updatedAnswers);
    };
    console.log(givenAnswer)
```

but in the console, it returns an array of `undefined`, while I want an array with the text of the answers. Can anyone help me, please?